# C++ reading char from stack to string results in "Unrecognized enum"

Tags: c++, char, stdstring

I am new to C++ and there must be something that I am missing. My code is this:

```
std::stack<char> operators;
std::stringstream stream;
stream.str("5.2 + 3");

while(stream.peek() != -1){
    char token = static_cast<char>(stream.get());
    //some code checking if the token is valid
    operators.push(token);
    auto tmp = operators.top(); //there I can still see the char (for example '+')
    std::string tmpStr = "" + tmp; //But when put into string, there is "Unrecognized enum"
}
```

The variable tmpStr is filled with "Unrecognized enum" instead of the contents of tmp.

I couldn't find any solution but I believe it must be something very simple.
Thanks for any help.

**Edit:**
So if I use tmpStr.push_back(tmp) it works. But then I use it like this:

```
std::queue<std::string> outQueue;
outQueue.push(" " + operators.top());
//some code
std::string result = "";
while(!outQueue.empty()){
    result.append(outQueue.front() + " ");
    outQueue.pop();
}
//result then has for example something like "5.2 own enum 3 own enum"
```

There on the positions that are appended from the *operators* stack, there is "own enum" and not what was actually saved there.

Comment: `"" + tmp` actually applies offset to pointer, it does not "add" char to the empty string. If you want to add char to string then you need to call `tmpStr.push_back(tmp);`.

Comment: That works, thanks. But then if I add the tmpStr to another string, it results in the same problem with operator += and even when I use append(). Is there also some special method for this?

Comment: Adding tmpStr to other strings or string literals should be fine because there are overloaded `operator +` to handle these cases. You should supply some code demonstrating this new problem.

Comment: Other ways to construct `tmpStr` from a single `char` are `std::string tmpStr(1, tmp);` and `std::string tmpStr(&tmp, 1);`

Comment: I've edited the post, so you can see the new problem. Where there is `" " + operators.top()` I tried  using temporary string variable using the push_back method and then inserting, but that did not help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop doing `"" + something`!

**This is C++ and it will not magically make a string object out of a string literal.**

If the above code actually compiles, it means that `somethign` is of some integral type and you are taking a stack pointer (const char*) of the location that "" points to and adding a pointer offset onto that. You are not reading some **random data** until the next NULL.

If you want to convert something to a string you need to convert it. The standard way to this is though a output stream operator.

```
enum OP
{
    OP_ADD,
    OP_SUB,
    OP_DIV,
    OP_MUL
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, OP op)
{
    switch (op)
    {
        case OP_ADD:
            os << "ADD";
            break;
        case OP_SUB:
            os << "SUB";
            break;
        case OP_DIV:
            os << "DIV";
            break;
        case OP_MUL:
            os << "MUL";
            break;
        default:
            throw std::logic_error("Invalid OP");
    }
}
```

This can then be used like so:

```
OP op = OP_ADD;
std::stringstream buff;
buff << op;
std::string sop = buff.str();
```

But since the above code it quite stupid, I have a shorthand for the object to string conversion:

```
template <typename T>
std::string to_string(T value)
{
    std::stringstream buff;
    buff << value;
    return buff.str();
}
```

This can then be used like so:

```
OP op = OP_ADD;
std::string sop = to_string(op);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! Hard getting used to it after doing C#.

Comment: The moment I saw "" + something, all alarm bells went off... I was thinking JavaScript, but yea C# does that too.